# Avoid temp table with group by on multiple columns from different table

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, temp-tables

Is it possible to create an index such that a temp table is not created where the group by is grouping on two or more columns from different tables?

Example:

```
SELECT T1.c1, T2.c2, COUNT(*)
FROM T1
JOIN T2 USING (pk)
WHERE
 T1.c3 = 100
GROUP BY T1.c1, T2.c2
```

What would be the combination of index'es that I could use so that a temp table is not created?

Answer (score 1):

No, read the [explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) at first point of the first list. The only usable index in this query could be on `T1.c3` column. You can avoid the temporary table by creating a view with joined both tables and grouping it explicitly.